Implementation of a non-constant operator[] for the Polynomial template class
I have created a Polynomial class and I want to add this functionality, specifically, to implement a non-constant operator[] for the Polynomial template, which:

will allow setting the value of the coefficient for a given degree (as in the example above)
will allow reading the value of the coefficient for a given degree (i.e., the code int cv = p[4]; should work)
will work in O(1) time if the polynomial degree does not change
will not change the degree of the polynomial if no assignment was made.

The last requirement can be expressed with the following test:
Polynomial<int> p;
p[2] = 1;
ASSERT_EQUAL(p.Degree(), 2);
int x = p[5];
ASSERT_EQUAL(x, 0);
ASSERT_EQUAL(p.Degree(), 2);  // We did not assign anything to p[5], so the degree of the polynomial did not change.

Here is my implementation:
#include "test_runner.h"
#include "profile.h"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
class Polynomial {
private:
  std::vector<T> coeffs_ = {0};

  void Shrink() {
    while (coeffs_.size() > 1 && coeffs_.back() == 0) {
      coeffs_.pop_back();
    }
  }

public:
  Polynomial() = default;
  Polynomial(vector<T> coeffs) : coeffs_(std::move(coeffs)) {
    Shrink();
  }

  template<typename Iterator>
  Polynomial(Iterator first, Iterator last) : coeffs_(first, last) {
    Shrink();
  }

  bool operator ==(const Polynomial& other) const {
    return coeffs_ == other.coeffs_;
  }

  bool operator !=(const Polynomial& other) const {
    return !operator==(other);
  }

  int Degree() const {
    return coeffs_.size() - 1;
  }

  Polynomial& operator +=(const Polynomial& r) {
    if (r.coeffs_.size() > coeffs_.size()) {
      coeffs_.resize(r.coeffs_.size());
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i != r.coeffs_.size(); ++i) {
      coeffs_[i] += r.coeffs_[i];
    }
    Shrink();
    return *this;
  }

  Polynomial& operator -=(const Polynomial& r) {
    if (r.coeffs_.size() > coeffs_.size()) {
      coeffs_.resize(r.coeffs_.size());
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i != r.coeffs_.size(); ++i) {
      coeffs_[i] -= r.coeffs_[i];
    }
    Shrink();
    return *this;
  }


  class IndexProxy {
  public:
    IndexProxy(Polynomial& poly, size_t degree) : poly_(poly), degree_(degree) {}
    T& operator =(const T& value) {
      if (degree_ >= poly_.coeffs_.size() && value == 0) {
        static T zero = T(0);
        return zero;
      } else if (degree_ >= poly_.coeffs_.size() && value != 0) {
        poly_.coeffs_.resize(degree_ + 1);
      }

      poly_.coeffs_[degree_] = value;
      return poly_.coeffs_[degree_];
    }


    bool operator ==(const T& other) const {
        return poly_.coeffs_[degree_] == other;
    }
    bool operator !=(const T& other) const {
        return poly_.coeffs_[degree_] != other;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out) const {
        return out << poly_.coeffs_[degree_];
    }



    operator T() const {
      return std::as_const(poly_)[degree_];
    }
    
    private:
      Polynomial& poly_;
      size_t degree_;
  };




  T operator [](size_t degree) const {
    return degree < coeffs_.size() ? coeffs_[degree] : 0;
  }

  IndexProxy operator [](size_t degree) {
    return IndexProxy(*this, degree);
  }


  T operator ()(const T& x) const {
    T res = 0;
    for (auto it = coeffs_.rbegin(); it != coeffs_.rend(); ++it) {
      res *= x;
      res += *it;
    }
    return res;
  }

The key implementation lies in class IndexProxy in T& operator=(const T& value) (simple operator[], which returns T& won't work, because it will change degree of the polynomial). In case of T& operator= in IndexProxy class I return 0, if new coefficient is bigger than degree of polynomial and inserted value is 0. Otherwise it changes degree to desired input.
But during the check I am getting the following assertion:
for (size_t i = 10; i < 50000; ++i) {
      ASSERT_EQUAL(poly[i], 0); //In this place assert happens
      ASSERT_EQUAL(poly.Degree(), 5);
    }

TestNonconstAccess fail: Assertion failed: 0 != 0 hint: poly[i] != 0

From the test it looks like an "undefined behaviour". What am I missing in this case?

You are assuming that IndexProxy::operator T() will be called as part of the equality comparison, but in fact it's IndexProxy::operator==() that is called. That method doesn't perform any check against the degree.

Why does operator= return T&? The conventional choice would be IndexProxy& and return *this;.

Your code is not exhibiting undefined behaviour.   It is demonstrating a misunderstanding of basic rules of standard C++.  Your set of requirements can't (simultaneously) all be met.  In your test case p[2] = 1 and int x = p[5] both call the SAME overload of Polynomial's operator[]()  i.e.  the non-const one if present, since p is not const  (if there was no non-const overload then p[2] = 1 is a diagnosable error).     Rules of the language don't select the const version of operator[]() just because the result of p[5] is used to initialise x

@Peter You are missing that the non-const operator[] returns a proxy object not a real reference. Properly implemented the proxy object can enforce the requirements that the OP has.

poly[i] == 0 does not do any bounds-checking - the only operation that does is the assignment operator.

Also, your evaluation is wrong. For instance, evaluating ax gives a (0 * x + a) for any value of x.
